# Can I boot a RPI 3 from an old HDD (not SSD) using Berryboot?

Tags: hard-drive, berryboot

I know this question has been asked a few times, but technology changes and so I wanted to check the current state.
Is it possible to re-purpose and old (rotating, magnetic) usb Harddisk to boot my Raspberry Pi 3 from?
(and/or would it be possible with a RPI4?)
Would I still need a micro SD card?
your insights/experience is much appreciated,
chris V

Comment: If you have a USB carrier it's perfectly possible to boot a 3B, 3B+ or 3A+ from any USB stick, hard drive or SSD without an SDCard. The 3B needs to boot once from a SDCard to set the OTP bit for USB booting.

Comment: Thank you @Dougie.  For now I have the Berryboot bootloader on the SD card.  This then loads the OS from my old 500GB hdd.  I think I read somewhere that once that OTP bit is set, there is no turning back to "boot from SD card".  Can you confirm this?

Comment: Nope not true. The OTP just means boot from USB if there's no SDCard or no bootable files on the SDCard.